# Where is the tax free in Mariehamn Airport located?

Tags: airports, duty-free, mhq, aland

I recently flew from Mariehamn to Stockholm but I couldn't find the tax free. Reading about the airport I've found that it's actually excempt from the EU VAT area and the tax free is actually tax free (not like in other EU airports on EU flights), even when flying to Sweden or Finland!

Where can I find the tax free in Mariehamn Airport?

Comment: What makes you think there is one? There is no tax free shop listed under 'services' on the airport's official web page.